# How do i get the index position that i want from a list?

Tags: python

```
default_options = [
    {'name': 'Budda Bowl (vg)', 'sell_for': 25, 'cost_to_make': 20, 'cook_time': 10, 'cook_time_stdev': 3},
    {'name': 'Eye Fillet Steak', 'sell_for': 55, 'cost_to_make': 25, 'cook_time': 7, 'cook_time_stdev': 1},
    {'name': 'Spaghetti Bolognese', 'sell_for': 30, 'cost_to_make': 22, 'cook_time': 40, 'cook_time_stdev': 5},
    {'name': 'Pad Thai (seafood)', 'sell_for': 22, 'cost_to_make': 17, 'cook_time': 30, 'cook_time_stdev': 1}]
```

So if I wanted to pick the index 0 I can do

```
print(default_options[0])
```

but now after I gotten the index that I want, how do I get just only the name of the dish. What should I do ?

Result that i wanted is -> 'name': 'Budda Bown(vg)'

```
print(default_board[0][0])
```

is not working for me

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

The first index is correct since `default_options` is a list, however every element is a dictionary, therefore you should call the corresponding key. In your case, if you want the name of the dish of the first element you should use:

```
print(default_options[0]['name'])
```

This will print out just "Budda Bowl (vg)".

Answer (score 0):

```
print(default_options[0]["name"])
```

```
OUTPUT:
Buda Bowl (vg)
```

(if you want it to return "name = "dish"" then do)

```
print("name =",default_options[0]["name"])
```

what you are storing the variables in is a dictionary not a list.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(list(default_options[0].items())[0])
```